# MFC: Delete elements from GUI

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, mfc

After tinkering and modifying a GUI I have been working on for some time I ended up with a group of EditControllers and Radio Buttons that I do not need any more, so I would like to get rid of them. However, if I simply delete them from the GUI edit, I get assertion errors. How am I supposed to get rid of these elements?

Comment: Seeing one of the error messages would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove all code from your program that refers to the deleted controls. For each control you want to delete, take its ID and search the source for statements that refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Start like this:

1. Check the ID of that given control. Copy it. Now remove the control from dialog resource.
2. Ensure that ID is not **used** by other dialogs. If not, you can use following.
3. Delete that ID from resource.h.
4. When you compile it, you'd get error (around `GetDlgItem`, `DDX_Control` etc). Remove or comment them. Remove appropriate `CWnd`-derived variables (like `CEdit`, `CComboBox` etc).
5. You are done!

If given ID is used by other dialogs (check it from Resource View's context menu **Resource Symbols...**), then you cannot directly remove it from resource editor. You, however, need to remove it from appropriate implementation file (of `CDialog`/`CPropertyPage`-derived class).